# How I can use storage data in http request?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I cant use “ids” variable in another function. Alltimes returned as undefined. How i can use this variable. This is so important for me. Because i will use this variable at http requests.

```
    storageGet(){
        this.storage.get('favoriteStory').then((val) => {
                  this.ids = val;
                });
              }


    getStories() {
        return this.http.get("https://myaddress.com/funnies/"+this.ids+"/favorites/")
          .map(response => response.json())
      }
```

Comment: More of the code would be handy. I have a fairly good idea of where things are going wrong, but I can't say for sure right now.

Comment: You should show how you are using these two mehods. Reading from storage is async, so you need to wait until it's resolved and "ids" is set.

Comment: @jal_a precisely what I was thinking. I suspect he's calling both methods one after the other without waiting for the promise to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switchMap()` from `rxjs/operator`.

First, you get the data from storage and convert the `Promise` to an `Observable` with `from` method. Then map the result it into the inner observable using `switchMap`.

```
import {from} from 'rxjs';

import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';


storageGet(){
    return this.storage.get('favoriteStory');
}


getStories(){
    return from(this.storageGet()).pipe(
      switchMap(storageVal =>this.http.get("https://myaddress.com/funnies/"+storageVal+"/favorites/")),
      map(response => response.json())
    )
}
```

Then you can `subscribe` to `getStories()` method.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
storageGet(){
    // return a promise
    if(this.ids !== undefined) {
        return Promise.resolve(this.ids);
    }

    return this.storage.get('favoriteStory').then((val) => {
          this.ids = val;
          // return the value so that the next `then` in chain can have access to it
          return val;
    });
}


getStories() {
        return this.storageGet().then(ids => {          
           return this.http.get("https://myaddress.com/funnies/"+ids+"/favorites/")
              .map(response => response.json())
        })
}
```